# Количество операторов и операндов

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Нужно реализовать разбор кода С# по метрике Холстеда. Собственно, необходимо найти все операторы и операнды программы. Возникает такой вопрос: сколько в данном куске кода операторов и операндов:

```
Cells = new ObservableCollection<Cell>();

var cell = new Cell { 
 Text = string.Format("{0}", i) 
};
```

Также интересует следующее: являются ли операторами агрументы цикла for?

```
 for (var col = 0; col < 4; col++)
```

Возможно, глупый вопрос, но почему-то поставил меня в тупик.

Comment: Вам надо написать всего-навсего парсер C#. Это не так уж и сложно, но поработать придётся.

В C# нет общепринятого понятия «оператора» и «операнда», так что вам придётся посмотреть в определение метрики Холстеда.

Comment: Информация с Хабра: "..К метрикам основанных на подсчете некоторых единиц в коде программы, относят метрики Холстеда. Данные метрики основаны на следующих показателях:

 n1 — число уникальных операторов программы, включая символы-

 разделители, имена процедур и знаки операций (словарь операторов),

 n2 — число уникальных операндов программы (словарь операндов),

 N1 — общее число операторов в программе,

 N2 — общее число операндов в программе,

 n1' — теоретическое число уникальных операторов,

 n2' — теоретическое число уникальных операндов."

Как быть?

Comment: Ох уж эти любители строгих классификаций... 

В самом деле как-то не все тут однозначно.

--

Рассмотрим `for (...)`.

С одной стороны понятно:

Само слово for -- оператор. Его операндами являются *список выражений* и тело цикла (тут не приведено, обычно его тоже относят к операторам, но здесь по идее он д.б. операндом).

Список выражений -- это операнд, состоящий из элементов списка, которые тоже являются  операндами.

Разделители `;` это операции.

И т.д. рекурсивно.

А вопрос (неоднозначность) в том, включать ли в число операндов (при подсчете `for`) и сам список, или только его элементы?

Comment: С циклом for все, допустим, понятно. За это спасибо.
Так сколько операторов и операндов в куске кода, о котором я писал?
____
Всё еще актуально!

Comment: @Евгений Шилин: так всё ещё непонятно:

1. Что называется у вас оператором программы? Например: 

        if (false)
            this.DataContextChanged += (o, args) =>
                { MessageBox.Show(42); throw new Exception(); };

    это сколько операторов?

2. Как определяется уникальность? `MessageBox.Show(this.ToString())` для разных типов `this` — уникальные?

3. Что такое «теоретическое число»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Операнды

При расчете метрики Холстеда используются следующие операнды:

Идентификаторы – все идентификаторы, которые не являются
зарезервированными словами.

Идентификаторы типов&nbsp; - зарезервированные слова, обозначающие
тип данных: `bool`, `char`, `double`, `float`, `int`, `long`, `short`, `signed`, `unsigned`, `void`.

Константы - числовые, символьные, строковые.

Операторы

Ключевые слова следующих категорий, которые интерпретируются
как операторы:

Идентификаторы класса памяти: `inline`, `register`, `static`,
`typedef`, `virtual`, `mutable`.
Квалификаторы типа: `const`,
`friend`, `volatile`.
Зарезервированные слова:  `asm`, `break`, `case`, `class`, `continue`, `default`, `delete`, `do`, `else`, `enum`,
`for`, `goto`, `if`, `new`, `operator`, `private`, `protected`, `public`, `return`, `sizeof`,
`struct`, `switch`, `this`, `union`, `while`, `namespace`, `using`, `try`, `catch`, `throw`,
`const_cast`, `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `typeid`, `template`,
`explicit`, `true`, `false`, `typename`.

Операторы языка программирования: `!` `!=` `%` `%=`  `&&&`  `||`  `&=`  `( )`  `*`
`*=`   `+`    `++`     `+=`  и т.д.

Следующие управляющие структуры: `for(…)`, `if (…)`, `switch (…)`, `while for (…) and catch (...)` интерпретируются как один оператор.

Поэтому  `for (var col = 0; col < 4; col++)` это один оператор.

Из приведенного кода `cell` и `i` операнды.

Все остальное операторы.

Comment: Приведённая вами классификация слишком C++-центрична. В C# нету `inline`, `register`, `friend`, `asm`, `delete`, `union`, `*_cast` и т. п., зато есть атрибуты (типа `[Obsolete]`), [контекстные ключевые слова](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/the35c6y.aspx) и лямбда-выражения, которые не вполне ложатся на неё.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Думаю, что теперь разберусь.

Comment: `Из приведенного кода cell и i операнды.`
А разве `Cells` не будет являться таковым, даже если он объявлен не в этом куске кода?